# Wrong replacement in R

Tags: r

I have two variables A and B

```
a              b
234323432      NA
234324343      NA
238432788      NA
6786686        576575 
97892734       NA
87236488       NA
234683246      NA
```

I want to replace b with a whenver b is NA
I tried with

```
la2$b[is.na(la2$b)] <- la2$a
```

first three NA's are replaced correctly but after 4th row the 5th row of b is replace by 4th row of a. Is there any specific reason for wrong replacement.

```
a              b
234323432      234323432
234324343      234324343
238432788      238432788
6786686        576575 
97892734       6786686
87236488       97892734
234683246      87236488
```

expected output below

```
a              b
234323432      234323432
234324343      234324343
238432788      238432788
6786686        576575 
97892734       97892734
87236488       87236488
234683246      234683246
```

Comment: You need to have the same selection logic on both sides of the assignment. You should have gotten a warning about a mismatch in sizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match the indices of the two vectors, you can try

```
la2$b[is.na(la2$b)] <- la2$a[is.na(la2$b)]
#          a         b
#1 234323432 234323432
#2 234324343 234324343
#3 238432788 238432788
#4   6786686    576575
#5  97892734  97892734
#6  87236488  87236488
#7 234683246 234683246
```

---

If computation time matters (in the case of large data sets), it should be preferable to compute the indices once and store them in a vector `idx`, as pointed out by @docendodiscimus.

```
idx <- is.na(la2$b)
la2$b[idx] <- la2$a[idx]
```

**data**

```
la2 <- structure(list(a = c(234323432L, 234324343L, 238432788L, 6786686L, 
            97892734L, 87236488L, 234683246L), b = c(NA, NA, NA, 576575L, 
            NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("a", "b"), class = "data.frame", 
            row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: Or, to avoid redundant computation of `is.na(la2$b)` you can use an index: `idx <- is.na(la2$b); la2$b[idx] <- la2$a[idx]`

Comment: @docendodiscimus You are right, of course. Actually I had thought about that. I never know whether one-liners are preferred over somewhat more efficient two-liners ;-) Aligning two commands with a semicolon is a smart way to achieve both :-)

Comment: Nothing wrong with your one-liner answer here :) I just think it's a good opportunity to show how you can easily write more efficient code in many situations (the difference may be negligible for small to medium data but certainly noticeable on large data sets)

Comment: @docendodiscimus I agree; probably I should have added this second option in my answer. I think it's good that you have posted that comment.

Comment: Feel free to include it in your answer if you like it

Comment: @docendodiscimus Thank you. I believe that your comment and the short discussion convey the information very well, but an edit might indeed render this information more easily visible.